# iPhone UIButton won't disable after setting enabled = NO

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton

I'm doing the HelloPoly example from the Stanford class and trying to disable the increase/decrease buttons when appropriate

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PolygonShape.h"

@interface Controller : NSObject {
    IBOutlet UIButton *decreaseButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *increaseButton;
    IBOutlet UILabel *numberOfSidesLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *angleLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *minSidesLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *maxSidesLabel;

    IBOutlet PolygonShape *polygonShape;
}


-(IBAction)decrease:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)increase:(id)sender;
-(void)updateUI;

@end
```

and then in my Controller.m, none of the effects on the increase or decrease button take

```
-(IBAction)decrease:(id)sender
{
    //NSLog(@"-");
    polygonShape.numberOfSides--;
    if (polygonShape.numberOfSides == polygonShape.minimumNumberOfSides)
        decreaseButton.enabled = NO;
    else 
        decreaseButton.enabled = YES;

    self.updateUI;

    increaseButton.enabled = NO;
    increaseButton.highlighted = YES;
    increaseButton.hidden = YES;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the buttons are wired (i.e., not-nil)?

Comment: Don't use FALSE/TRUE. (YES/NO are the standard constants for ObjC booleans.) And your call to updateUI should be a message call: [self updateUI];

Comment: Are you sure that you hooked up the decreaseButton and increaseButton properly in the IB, in both directions.  Also, try sticking with YES and NO.   What happens in updateUI? (which could be called as [self ubpdateIU] - since it's more Objective-C like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I handled it so long ago, a bit more verbose than your version but basically the same, as in the comment, check your connections in IB, and stick with YES/NO everywhere as well.

```
- (IBAction)decrease:(id)sender {
if ([shape numberOfSides] >= minNumberOfSides) {
    [shape setNumberOfSides:[shape numberOfSides]-1];
    NSLog(@"Decrease!");
}
[self updateInterface];
}

- (IBAction)increase:(id)sender {
if ([shape numberOfSides] <= maxMumberOfSides) {
    [shape setNumberOfSides:[shape numberOfSides]+1];
    NSLog(@"Increase!");
}
[self updateInterface];
}

- (void)updateInterface {
numberOfSidesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [shape numberOfSides]];
nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [shape name]];

if ([shape numberOfSides] == minNumberOfSides) {
    decreaseButton.enabled = NO;
}
else {
    decreaseButton.enabled = YES;
}

if ([shape numberOfSides] == maxNumberOfSides) {
    increaseButton.enabled = NO;
}
else {
    increaseButton.enabled = YES;
}
}
```

Comment: Buttons were not wired. Doh. Thank you.  I hope later I learn how to wire them in code.  I'm not used to all this gui programming :)



also for the others, TRUE is the same as YES, and dot notation is the same as [], but thx for the attempt to help :)

NSLog(@"YES == TRUE?: %d", (YES==TRUE));

2010-04-08 12:29:17.860 HelloPoly[5897:207] YES == TRUE?: 1

Comment: Sure YES == TRUE and NO == FALSE, and you can mix them, it's just more  Objective-C/Cocoa like to stick with YES NO.  Glad we could help!